# NodeJs with Express and Handlebars - handlebars.engine is undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, handlebars.js, viewengine

I am following the tutorials in O'Reilly's "Web Development with Node & Express" by Ethan Brown.

They use handlebars as the view engine.

Here is my code:

```
var express = require ('express'),
    handlebars = require('express3-handlebars'),
    app = express();

handlebars.create({ defaultLayout: 'main' });
app.engine('handlebars', handlebars.engine);
```

The problem I am having is that handlebars.engine is undefined, resulting in a "Callback function expected" error when running the application.

I have tried searching online without any luck.

Is this some legacy syntax with handlebars? My packages have installed fine and I have tried reinstalling them.

Is there a fix/updated code for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to get the engine from the object you got from the `create()`-call!

Like this:

`var expHbs = require('express-handlebars');
var handlebars = expHbs.create({
    defaultLayout: 'layout',
    extname: '.hbs',
    helpers: handlebarsHelpers
});
app.engine('.hbs', handlebars.engine);
app.set('view engine', '.hbs');`

Just saying: `express3-handlebars` got renamed to `express-handlebars`. You should consider switching.

Comment: Thanks so much. Was really stumped on this. For the purposes of this book, I'm going to use the old one, but will have a play around with the renamed one. Are all the methods and syntax the same? Is it just the name that changed? If so, I probably will make the switch now

Comment: The most things are the same, but some functions, like `res.status(404).end();` are not allowed anymore (`req.sendStatus(404);` is now the correct one)

Here is the changelog, since renamed from `express3-handlebars`:
https://github.com/ericf/express-handlebars/blob/master/HISTORY.md#100-2014-08-07